# Access Property Using Reflection C#

Tags: c#, linq, generics, expression

I have came up with a function that orders a list by a specified value and then returns a new object value. Where I am stuck is in the .`Select` statement when trying to get the `StatValue`. The current example below is what I am trying to do (which obviously doesnt work)

I can get a string value of the passed in order by property, I need to use this property string when getting the `StatValue` i.e x.GoalsPerGame

```
private static TodayStatsItem GetStatsValue<TOrderBy>(Expression<Func<PlayerItem, bool>> filter,
    Expression<Func<PlayerItem, TOrderBy>> orderBy, IEnumerable<PlayerItem> items, string desc)
{
    var itemSorted = new TodayStatsItem {
        PlayerItems = items.AsQueryable().OrderBy(orderBy).Select(x => new TodayStatsViewModel
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            //StatValue = ((MemberExpression)orderBy.Body).Member.Name.ToString() // returns GoalsPerGame
            StatValue = x.((MemberExpression)orderBy.Body).Member.Name.ToString() // attempt to access property
        }),
        StatName = desc        
    };
    return itemSorted;
}
```

The call to this method would looks like this.

```
this.LeagueItem.Add(GetStatsValue(null, x => x.GoalsPerGame, this.GameReport, "Goals Per Game"));
```

Is this any way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to (re)use the given `orderBy` expression to obtain the desired values (`Compile().Invoke(item)` - though you may want to compile it only once and reuse the resulting function) . No need for reflection as far as I can see.

Comment: Could you show an example of this please? Also would this be more efficient than Reflection?

Comment: `orderBy.Compile()` gives you a `Func<PlayerItem, TOrderBy>`. In your example that would be a function that returns the `GoalsPerGame` value of a given player item. So you just call that function on each item: `StatValue = compiledOrderBy.Invoke(x)` - or just `StatValue = compiledOrderBy(x)`. As for performance, reflection tends to involve additional checks so it's typically slower.

Comment: Just implemented this and it also works perfectly. Now I just need to decide which is most suitable for the application. Thanks for this suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method for getting the property value from an object with the specified property name using reflection:

```
using System.Reflection;

public static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    return property.GetValue(obj);
}
```

In your case:

```
string propertyName = ((MemberExpression)orderBy.Body).Member.Name.ToString();
StatValue = (int)GetPropertyValue(x, propertyName); // I'm assuming StatValue is of type int
```

But to achieve what you are trying to do, you could first [compile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362(v=vs.110).aspx) the `orderBy` expression and then use it to get the value, which is faster than reflection.

Like this:

```
private static TodayStatsItem GetStatsValue<TOrderBy>(Expression<Func<PlayerItem, bool>> filter,
Expression<Func<PlayerItem, TOrderBy>> orderBy, IEnumerable<PlayerItem> items, string desc)
{
    Func<PlayerItem, TOrderBy> orderByDeleg = orderBy.Compile();
    var itemSorted = new TodayStatsItem {
    PlayerItems = items.AsQueryable().OrderBy(orderByDeleg).Select(x => new TodayStatsViewModel
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            StatValue = orderByDeleg(x)
        }),
        StatName = desc
    };
    return itemSorted;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I see a comment by Pieter on the OP that suggests Reflection may not be needed. Do you happen to know which of the two ways would be more efficient?

Also thank you for this answer, its really helpful!

Comment: Check my updated answer. The second way, using the compiled delegate, is faster than using reflection. Reflection is (generally speaking) rather slow.

Comment: Looks exactly like what I had tried after Pieters suggestion. Is there no difference between using orderBy over the orderByDeleg in the .OrderBy()?

Comment: Using `orderByDeleg` is better, because it doesn't need to be compiled again. I updated my answer.

Comment: @BadDub: If you're working with Linq to SQL then you need to pass an expression to `OrderBy`. If you're operating on in-memory objects then you don't need those expressions and `AsQueryable` calls at all here.

Comment: The items object is a list in memory at this stage. So I removed the Expression on the orderBy, but that then gives an error saying 'Func<PlayerItem, TOrderBy>' does not contain a definition for 'Compile''

Comment: @BadDub: that's because a `Func` is already compiled. An expression is actually a tree-like data structure that represents the original code, it's not executable unless you compile it. Useful for Linq-to-SQL (which translates expressions to SQL, so the database can do the filtering and sorting), but slower and more cumbersome when you're working with in-memory objects.

Comment: The `x => x.GoalsPerGame` that you're passing to your method gets compiled as either a function or an `Expression` tree structure, depending on the parameter type. In the latter case, it's shorthand for `Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<PlayerItem, TOrderBy>), Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof(PlayerItem).GetProperty("GoalsPerGame")), parameter)`, where `parameter` is the result of `Expression.Parameter(typeof(TOrderBy), "x")`.